# Custom Button (Solid Left Arrow) in android using shape drawable in android

Tags: android, button, shapedrawable

I want make a custom button in android `left solid arrow` (only arrow shape not its background).

[image]

How can I create this arrow button using shape drawable XML in android.

I know how to create rectangle button but not arrow.

Anybody who knows it please tell me how to do.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I can't post code, only show you where to go.
But the ultimate answer is to use a pathshape button. Then it handles everything for you.

Create the paths by following the information at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html
 
You can learn more about shapes at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/Shape.html
Finally you can learn about tying them together at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/PathShape.html

That way you can do it even in XML. And there's a variety of arc path methods. Check it out!